# HCF LCM Question

Tags: elementary-number-theory, arithmetic

$540= 2^2 \times 3^3 \times 5$
 Find the smallest positive integer $K$ such that $\frac{540}{k}$ is a cube number .

Answer (score 2):

$540=2^2\cdot3^3\cdot 5$ . We have to divide by a number $k=2^a3^b5^c$ with $a\equiv 2\bmod 3,b\equiv0\bmod 3$ and $c\equiv1\bmod 3$. Clearly the smallest choices are $a=2,b=0,c=1$. So $k=2^25^1$.

Comment: Why a must be 2 And c must be 1? I thought we have to make the power to become a cube power ?  means 2 X 5^2 to make it 2^3 X 3^3x 5^3

Comment: notice $540/k=2^{2-a}3^{3-b}5^{1-c}$. If we want this to be a cube then $2-a,3-b$ and $1-c$ must all  be multiples of $3$.

Comment: @DarrellTan Notice we want to make $\frac{540}{k}$ a cube, not $540k$.

Comment: If a cube has any powers of 5 it has to have at least 3 powers of 5.  As 540 has only one power of 5 we can't leave any in, so we have to divide the 5 out.  Same thing with the 2.  The only possible cubes are 540/540= 1  and 540/2^2\*5 = 27.

Comment: Ohh ya I got it . Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

To be a cube, a numbers prime factors must be a multiple of 3 power.  $540 = 2^2*3^3*5$ so the only powers that are 3 or higher is $3^3$.  So the only possible answers are $540/20 = 27$ or $540/540 = 1$.

From your comment it sounds like you meant to ask what is the least $k$ so that $540*k$ is a cube.  In which case we must bump up the power of 2 and 5.

$(2^2*3^3*5)*2*5^2 = 2^3*3^3*5^3 \iff 540*50 = 27000 = 30^3$